# Excel - Pipe delimited text file delimiter not aligned

Tags: excel

I have an excel file where in it has 3 columns and the first row having the column name. When I converted it into a pipe-delimited CSV, I noticed that the pipe symbol of the succeeding rows is not aligned to the symbol location of the first row when opened in a text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++:

E.g.

```
Column A|Column B|Column C
1|2|3
2|22222|333333
3|3333|44
```

What I wanted is like this

```
Column A|Column B|Column C
1       |2       |3
2       |22222   |333333
3       |3333    |44
```

I have tried putting the contents in Middle Align and Center content in Excel but it still gives me the non-aligned pipe symbols. Manually putting space to align the pipe symbols can be time consuming.

May I know what can be tried to achieve the desired result? If needed to be done programmatically, I will appreciate it too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a console application that is pushed into a Github repo called [Pipe-Delimited-Text-File-to-String-Table-Conversion](https://github.com/jrossc/Pipe-Delimited-Text-File-to-String-Table-Conversion) for this. Hope that you take and look and this answers your question.

You are also welcome to submit improvements to the code.

Code by the way is written in C#.